# How to release it?

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone Development.

```
+ (id<GMGridViewLayoutStrategy>)strategyFromType:(GMGridViewLayoutStrategyType)type
{
    id<GMGridViewLayoutStrategy> strategy = nil;

    switch (type) {
        case GMGridViewLayoutVertical:
            strategy = [[GMGridViewLayoutVerticalStrategy alloc] init];
            break;
        case GMGridViewLayoutHorizontal:
            strategy = [[GMGridViewLayoutHorizontalStrategy alloc] init];
            break;
        case GMGridViewLayoutHorizontalPagedLTR:
            strategy = [[GMGridViewLayoutHorizontalPagedLTRStrategy alloc] init];
            break;
        case GMGridViewLayoutHorizontalPagedTTB:
            strategy = [[GMGridViewLayoutHorizontalPagedTTBStrategy alloc] init];
            break;
    }

    return strategy;
}
```

Here I am calling that method:

```
gmGridView = [[GMGridView alloc] init];
gmGridView.layoutStrategy = [GMGridViewLayoutStrategyFactory strategyFromType:GMGridViewLayoutHorizontalPagedLTR];
[self.view addSubview:gmGridView];
```

Now my question is that how to release strategy object of strategyFromType method?Its giving me potential leak.and if i am going to release/autorelease,my application is crashing.
Please help meThanking you...

Comment: offtopic: you can simply shorten [[YourClass alloc] init] to [YouClass new]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return [strategy autorelease];
```

**UPDATE:**
The answer about returning an autoreleased object is correct, the problem is that the `GMGridView` uses `ARC` according to the description in the [project's site](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView).

> Requirements:
>
> iOS 4 and up
> Xcode 4.2 (GMGridView uses ARC)
> Frameworks: Foundation,
>   UIKit, CoreGraphics and QuartzCore

So i suppose you need to add it the project as sub module, but you can search a little about instructions...

Comment: whenever i released/autorelease that obj,application is crashing.

Comment: make sure that your layoutProperty property is declared with a retain : @property (retain, nonatomic) id<GMGridViewLayoutStrategy> layoutStrategy;

Comment: And don't forget to release gmGridView after added it as subview of self.view

Comment: so how can i release all objects of GMGridView.i mean how can i convert it into non-arc?

Comment: Try this search: https://www.google.bg/search?hl=bg&safe=off&q=arc+submodule+non-arc&oq=arc+submodule+non-arc&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...0.0.0.4575.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.Qrecd_LOPtM there are some other projects that are ARC enabled and some explanations how to use them in non-ARC project.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ARC` then you code is fine, but without `ARC` you should return an autoreleased object:

```
+ (id)strategyFromType:(GMGridViewLayoutStrategyType)type { 
    id strategy = nil;

   switch (type) {
         case GMGridViewLayoutVertical:
                strategy = [[GMGridViewLayoutVerticalStrategy alloc] init];
         break;
         case GMGridViewLayoutHorizontal:
             strategy = [[GMGridViewLayoutHorizontalStrategy alloc] init];
        break;
        case GMGridViewLayoutHorizontalPagedLTR:
            strategy = [[GMGridViewLayoutHorizontalPagedLTRStrategy alloc] init];
        break;
        case GMGridViewLayoutHorizontalPagedTTB:
          strategy = [[GMGridViewLayoutHorizontalPagedTTBStrategy alloc] init];
        break;
   }

   return [strategy autorelease];
}
```

All object that are return by methods should be `autorelease`, with the exception if `alloc`, `new` and any `copy` methods.

I would really suggest reading [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

Answer (score 0):

As you are returning the object you need to autorelease the object

```
return [strategy autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

return [strategy autorelease];
also
 [gmGridView release];

at the end of the function